# Auto Submit After Finished Fill Text Box

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have a problem,
i can't auto submit after fill the text box. i want to submit without the submit button.

check my code below

```
<?php
echo"
<form action='save.php' method='POST'>
<center>
Enter ID<br>
<input type='text' name='id'>
</center>
</form>
";
?>
```

Comment: Where is you javascript codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger the form's submit() event when the field loses focus. You can detect this by attaching a blur() event handler to it.

```
$("#field").blur(function() {
  $("#form").submit();
});
```

If you field doesn't have an ID or other means of easily identifying it (which I would recommend) you could also do something like this:(only used when you have one field)

```
$("#form :input").blur(function() {
  $("#form").submit();
});
```